# Creating a C++ visual studio project based on existing files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, visual-studio-2012

I've never worked with C++ or C. I'm trying to create a Visual studio project based on existing files which can be found here: [example1.cpp](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/SIXTH_EDITION/CODE/CHAPTER02/WINDOWS_VERSIONS/) together with the [resources](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/SIXTH_EDITION/CODE/include/). As you can see this is example code of a book for OpenGl. I have opengl and glut present on my computer and they work ( tested it).

Based on the files mentioned above a created an empty C++ project in visual studio 2012 (i also have other versions installed if you can provide a solution in 2010 or so). I included the header files & the source file. Though I still get the following in my IDE:

[image]

with errors such as:

> cannot open source file "Angle.h"

( Though the file is present in the project)

Can anyone tell me how I get these files to compile and run ?

Comment: I did not set any namespace. You think this is not possible to compile with visual studio ?

Comment: You should probably take some time to get used to the C/C++ style of building before building more complex applications that may require downloading libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file angel.h it's in the same path that the .cpp file.

Comment: Same as the answer above. That solved that problem, though still a problem with "vec2"

Comment: Ok, ¿vec2 is defined in the Angel namespace?

Comment: it seems so there is a struct vec2 in vec.h

Comment: I assume that the vec.h file is in the same path that "angel.h"

Comment: "angel.h" includes "vec.h" and its includes "angel.h"... It's weird. Try to include the files at the header of the cpp.

Answer (score 0):

Header files need to be in same directory with source files in order to use #include with quotes.

```
#include "header.h"
```

In other words Angel.h must be in same directory with example1.cpp.

However,you can add spesicific paths to your project from Project Settings>VC++ Directories and include header files which exists in those paths using

`#include <header.h>`